# De-Replicate an Access Database

Tags: ms-access-2007, replication, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an Access database that I need to reverse engineer into a website (app & data).

I just tried opening it with Outlook 2013 but I get an error that the database has replication enabled and it created with an earlier version of Access (something to that affect).

I assume it's just the replication that's the issue. Is there a way to remove the replication so I can poen it in Access 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it's not an easy job to unreplicate a database.

First I found WV Mitchell's VBA script that copies your tables into a new database:
http://www.wvmitchell.com/tips/Removing%20Access%20Replication.htm

That doesn't copy the Primary Keys or the Relationships, so I wrote a few quick and dirty VBA scripts to help with that.

Step 1: In the `MakeOneTable` function from the above script, I added this (above the db.Close line):

```
Dim td As TableDef
Dim idxLoop As Index

Set td = db.TableDefs(TableName)
For Each idxLoop In td.Indexes
    If idxLoop.Primary = True Then

        Dim colnames As String
        colnames = idxLoop.Fields
        colnames = Replace(colnames, ";+", "],[")
        colnames = Replace(colnames, "+", "[")
        colnames = colnames & "]"
        Debug.Print "DoCmd.RunSQL ""CREATE INDEX [PrimaryKey] ON [" & TableName & "] (" & colnames & ") With Primary;"""

        Exit For
    End If
Next idxLoop
```

That will output to the Debug (Immediate) Window some VBA code for creating the primary keys (as well as creating the new database and exporting the data to it - MV Mitchell's code). Copy that VBA code, put it into a module/macro in the new database, and run it - and it should create the Primary Keys.

Step 2: In the Old (replicated) database, run this VBA code, which will generate some more VBA code for creating the relationships:

```
Sub GenerateRelationshipCode()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT szRelationship,szObject,szReferencedObject FROM MSysRelationships ORDER BY szObject,szReferencedObject")
    rs.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rs.EOF

        Dim rsFields As DAO.Recordset
        Set rsFields = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MSysRelationships WHERE szRelationship = '" & Replace(rs.Fields(0), "'", "''") & "'")

        Dim PKFields As String, PKTable As String, FKFields As String, FKTable As String
        PKFields = "": PKTable = "": FKFields = "": FKTable = ""

        Do While Not rsFields.EOF
            PKFields = PKFields & rsFields("szReferencedColumn") & ","
            PKTable = rsFields("szReferencedObject")
            FKFields = FKFields & rsFields("szColumn") & ","
            FKTable = rsFields("szObject")
            rsFields.MoveNext
        Loop

        PKFields = Left(PKFields, Len(PKFields) - 1)
        FKFields = Left(FKFields, Len(FKFields) - 1)

        Debug.Print "Call AddRelationship(""" & rs.Fields(0) & """, """ & FKTable & """, """ & FKFields & """, """ & PKTable & """, """ & PKFields & """)"
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will need to run the output from the above against the new database, but you will also need this function:

```
Public Sub AddRelationship(Name As String, FKTable As String, FKFields As String, PKTable As String, PKFields As String)
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Name = "FK_" & Replace(FKTable, " ", "") & "_" & Replace(PKTable, " ", "") 'only enable this line if there aren't multiple relationships between same 2 tables
    strSQL = "ALTER TABLE [" & FKTable & "] " & _
    "  add constraint " & Name & " foreign key (" & FKFields & ") " & _
    "   references [" & PKTable & "](" & PKFields & ") "
    db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Run the generated VBA code in a module with the above function, and it should rebuild your relationships in the new database.

Note this code is quick & dirty so might need some bug fixes for your database/data.